# What happens to an object variable when it's reference is reassigned?

Tags: c#, .net, class, object, memory

When an object is instantiated with:

```
Foo objFoo = new Foo();
```

**What happens to it's memory allocation when it's reference, `objFoo`, is reassigned?**

```
objFoo = new Foo();
```

**What about when assigned to null?**

```
objFoo = null
```

Comment: This is what you're looking for : [Automatic memory management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691138(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Let me know the reason for mark it as Low Quality?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What happens to the currently using memory when we assign another instance to the object.

`objFoo` is a variable, not an object.

`objFoo = new Foo();` creates a new object (`new Foo()`) and assigns it to the `objFoo` variable.

If you invoke `objFoo = new Foo();` and there are no other variables referring to the same old object, then the old object will be eligible to be garbage collected.

Garbage collection does not happen immediately, but when it happens it would free the memory used by the old object.

Take a look at [this MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information about garbage collection.

> What happens to the memory when null is assigned to the object. ie., objFoo = null

Same as my previous note. If no other variable references the old object, the object will be eligible for garbage collection.

> In the first case i can access the new object where as in the second case, accessing value will give me null reference Exception.

The *variable* `objFoo` now does not refer to anything, that is why you are getting the exception when you try to access the object that it is referencing.

Comment: While not applying to the example class, it is important to note that Garbage Collection only automatically takes care of managed memory, if your class contains unmanaged memory (handles, streams, open files, etc.) then you will want to implement the [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface to properly free the memory.

Comment: @NathanC ...and try to enclose such resources in `using` statements, which implicitly call `Dispose`.

Answer (score 2):

When you remove the last reference to an object (in this case by setting the variable to **either** a new object or `null`, it's basically the same thing) it gets marked as being available to be garbage collected.

It doesn't mean the memory gets freed straight away (though that may happen) so if you had some non-managed way of accessing the memory it would still show as being "there" for a while.

At some point (which you can't determine) the memory is freed.

If you had other variables/lists etc. referencing the object then it's not eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 1):

At start, objFoo contains the reference to the first object's address in memory. When you create and assign the second object new Foo(), it creates a new object in memory and puts the new reference in objFoo. The old object, if not anymore referenced elsewhere in your code, becomes then a candidate to the garbage collector. You don't "override" the memory, you just use another memory range for the new object.

For your second point, it's almost the same. When you assign the null reference to the objFoo variable, the previous object will become a candidate to the GC if no other variables reference it. Since your variable actually do reference a null value and not a valid Foo object referenced in memory, you get this error.

In any case, you don't know exactly when the GC is gonna free the memory.